# Dataproc CPU usage too low even though all the cores got used

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

**Issue**: I run a spark job that uses up all the cores on all the nodes and yet in the Dataproc CPU monitoring graph the CPU usage touches a max of 12%

I have a dummy cluster with 2 nodes. Each node has:

1. 16 GiB memory
2. 16 cores

I start the spark session with the following configuration and run the following simple code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.\
config("spark.executor.cores","5").\
config("spark.executor.instances","6").\
config("spark.executor.memory","4100m").\
config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", False).\
getOrCreate()
df_sales = spark.read.parquet("gs://xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.appspot.com/spark_datasets/sales_parquet_dtc")
df_sales.count()
```

and, the yarn UI does show that I am able to allocate almost all of the clusters via YARN.

I can see in the progress bar that 30 tasks (6 executors* 5 cores per executor) are running in parallel. Hence all of the available cluster minus 2 cores that were intentionally left out for the OS was put to use

[image]

Yet, in the Monitoring, the CPU utilization touches a maximum of only 12.5%

[image]

Here is the DAG that got generated:

[image]

Why is CPU utilization such a small number? Am I wrong in assuming that the CPU utilization should have been higher than this?

I have also checked with `df_sales.withColumn("part_id", spark_partition_id()).groupby("part_id").count().collect()` the size of all my partitions are almost identical

Following are the stagewise DAGs:
Stage 0:
[image]

Stage 1:
[image]

Stage2:
Shows as skipped

Stage3:
[image]

Furthermore, When I look at the event timeline for the stage 1 (which is the one with 78 tasks) I can see that 30 cores are actually simultaneously busy most of the time

[image]

Am I wrong in thinking that any time when a vertical line intersects 30 green bars, 30 cores are simultaneously busy and at that moment the CPU utilization should be 30/32 at a minimum?

I have been able to get the CPU usage up to 63% according to the yarn metrics chart I am no longer sure how much to trust for the reasons given below:

Thinking that maybe my workload is very trivial compared to the network time I cached the data and then ran a few cpu intensive transformations on the data. I also read in pretty heavy partitions

```
#spark config
spark = SparkSession.builder.\
config("spark.executor.cores","15").\
config("spark.executor.instances","2").\
config("spark.executor.memory","12100m").\
config("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", False).\
config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", False).\
config("spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes","9g").\
getOrCreate()


#cache the data (the data is 55 GiBs in csv and ~10 GiB in memory deserialized)
df_covid = spark.read.csv("gs://monsoon-credittech.appspot.com/spark_datasets/covid40g.csv",
                          header=True, inferSchema=False)
df_covid.cache()
df_covid.count()


#Run heavy transformations
df_covid = df_covid.withColumn("catted",F.concat_ws('',*df_covid.columns))
df_covid = df_covid.withColumn("size0", F.length(F.split("catted", "a").getItem(0)))
df_covid = df_covid.withColumn("size1", F.length(F.split("catted", "a").getItem(1)))
df_covid = df_covid.withColumn("size2", F.length(F.split("catted", "a").getItem(2)))
df_covid.filter((df_covid.size0 > 5) & (df_covid.size1 > 5) & (df_covid.size2 > 5)).count()
```

I monitored the CPU usage via

1. Dataproc yarn CPU usage chart (touches 63% max)
2. `htop` from within workers (all cores are usually busy completely)

[image: dataproc yarn]

[image: htop in two nodes]
As you can see all the cores are busy and yet the YARN monitoring shows that max of 63% of my CPU got used

At this point I do not know how to make sense of the YARN monitoring live chart

Hoping someone helps me understand what is going on here

Comment: Could you add the DAG (from the UI) or physical plan of that `Stage 1`? Knowing which operations are being done will help to pinpoint where the bottleneck might be.

Comment: Thank you for your interest @Koedlt. I have updated the question as per your request. If you can help me understand why this could happen even though there are 30 tasks active at any time till they begin to finish I would be able to better help you help me. Does that not necessarily translate to a complete utilization of 30 cores till the very end? When the 30 tasks are running in parallel should the CPU utilization not be very high (ideally, greater than 30/32)?

Comment: Hey happy to help you! Before answering I just want to be sure that we're looking at the correct Stage here. Right now you have shown the Query tab, which shows some very interesting and relevant information to the question. The issue is that your screenshot shows the DAG of multiple stages. Could you also add another screenshot from the "Stages" tab at the top of your Web UI screen, and show what the DAG is of `Stage 1` only? Then I can be sure of which operations happen in that stage. I'll do my best to answer your question to the fullest, already have an idea of what might be happening.

Comment: @Koedlt - I have updated the question with the relevant DAGs. Please let me know in case anything else is needed. Looking forward to understanding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot of your progress bar does indeed show that there were 30 tasks running at the same time. This makes sense, given the amount of CPUs in your cluster (5 * 6 = 30).

In general, you have 1 cpu core per task (unless you set the `spark.task.cpus` config parameter to something different than the default 1, which you did not do). So you would indeed guess that if you have 30 tasks that are running, you would have a CPU utilization of +-94% (30/32).

What's going on here then, how come your utilization is so low? Well, **it is not because a task reserves 1 cpu that it really utilizes 1 cpu**. This means that there is something else that is stalling your tasks, and making your CPU wait. There is another bottleneck in the story.

What could those bottlenecks be? Let's take a closer look at Stage 1 (which is the stage we're talking about). The rough structure of this task is the following:

- **Scan parquet** (this is the reading of your files)

  - Possible bottlenecks:

    - If your underlying storage technology is slower than what your cpus can process (imagine using floppy disks to exaggerate)
    - If the network connection to your storage layer is overloaded
    - If the communication delay between your cpu and storage (your ping) is very large, your CPUs will have to wait too
- **WholeStageCodeGen** (your count happens here, which can be optimized by Spark)

  - No immediately obvious bottleneck here
- **Exchange** (this is a shuffle, because those 78 tasks calulcated a partial count, now a total count needs to be done so a shuffle is needed)

  - No immediately obvious bottleneck here, since the data being shuffled is so small

I would guess that something might be up with the reading of your file.

Try the following:

- Run this exact same code but with only 1 executor, with 1 CPU and check the CPU utilization.

  - If your CPU utilization goes closer to 100% efficiency, this might mean that either your network to your storage layer can't handle the traffic or your storage layer can't handle the necessary IO (does not seem very likely with these data volumes)
  - If it does not change, I would guess that the delay to your storage layer might be the culprit.

But to finish off: You're doing a `.count` operation on a parquet file that is +-10GB large. A `.count` operation reads a VERY small amount of data, and processes a VERY small amount of data. So your CPUs have to do VERY little work. This means that any work that your CPUs don't do but still use time (like sending read queries to your storage, ...) will actually use a proportionally large amount of time. I would guess that if you do more heavy work (for example `df.withColumn("substring", substring(col("MyStringCol"))).show`) your CPU utilization will go closer to your expected 94%.

Comment: I tried running the entire app with just 1 core and 1 executor and the results didn't change. I tried using something more computationally intensive than just a count - ```df_sales.select(F.concat(*df_sales.columns).alias("newcol")).select(F.countDistinct("newcol")).show()``` and results didn't change here either. Still, I am not able to cross that 15-20% CPU utilization. Also I see that in event timeline for the stage 1, any vertical line does intersect 30 cores in the green (updating the question to demonstrate the same), reinforcing that all the 30 cores are busy at that moment. Confused :(

Comment: Also, to decouple the application from network time I placed the file on the dataproc dfs and then ran the application. ```hdfs dfs -cp gs://xxxxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com/spark_datasets/sales_parquet hdfs://pyspark-33-m/tmp/sales_data/```. And then, ```df_sales = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://pyspark-33-m/tmp/sales_data/sales_parquet"); df_sales.count()``` and I still do not see CPU utilization crossing 20 %

Comment: That's some pretty great testing! At this point I'm starting to doubt whether we understand CPU utilization numbers correctly. Are you able to `ssh` into one of those 16 CPU nodes? Could you look at the output of some tool like `top` to see what the OS says is the CPU utilization?

Comment: I was able to give this time only today. I have tried looking at the htop command in the workers. 1. all the cores do fill up with blue threads momentarily. I guess the CPU usage in yarn collects the CPU usage at discrete times and connects them with a straight line and hence that brief moment of CPU spike is not caught 2. I tried looking at htop with the heavier ```concat.countDistinct``` command as well. All the cores do get used but, only at like 5% capacity. In htop there is just one blue bar showing. I am going to run the entire exercise on a bigger (~250GiB) file and update you

Comment: Ok awesome, good luck! Looking forward to see what happens :)

Comment: I was able to get the CPU usage up to 63%. I cached the data, ran heavy transformations and operated on large partitions. I have updated the question. The outputs of htop and yarn live chart are not consistent (I think). Eagerly looking forward to your thoughts on the same.

Comment: Also, I have made a final attempt. I created a udf that increments every character in a string column by 1. I applied this UDF ad nauseam to a string column (like 10 times) and managed to get the code runtime increased by 10 fold. Even then the highest CPU usage that I see is 71%. I do not know what could be the bottleneck beyond this. All the data is read in from inmemory cache

Comment: Hey I feel the original question might have been answered: the low usage is both due to small calculation load so lots of overhead and the yarn CPU usage seems to not be the same as actual CPU usage. Would you be OK with finishing off this question and making a new one about the difference between the yarn chart and the `htop` output? Then the question can stay focused. You can send me the link to that question here as a comment :)

Comment: Oh yes. I was thinking the same that at the end of the Rabbit hole I found only the reasons that you have suggested in your answer